# Access Denied HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: c#, registry

I'm getting: Access Denied HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

What is the wrong with this code?

```
var key = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Expression\\Encoder\\4.0";

using (var registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key))
{
    if (registryKey == null)
    {
        using (var newKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(key))
        {
            CheckInstallKey(newKey);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CheckInstallKey(registryKey);
    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

run your code as administrator

HKLM is just for local system and administrators

HKCU is for regular users

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: @AhmedAlayat run Visual Studio by right-click and choose "Run As Administrator"

Comment: [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698193/vista-vb-net-access-denied-while-writing-to-hkey-local-machine?rq=1)

Comment: thank you but is there any way to run only this code as admin not all of my program?

Comment: no, administrative priveleges given to process.

Comment: so if my program's user want to open it does he has to run it as admin

Comment: or you may store your data in HKEY_CURRENT_USER, it is no admin priveleges requeres

Comment: i have tried that but another .dll file can't load

Comment: why do you cheating system writing keys about encoder, if it is absent in system? just recommend user to install and give him link